# Avoid overlap/ entangling in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, overlap, force-layout

How do I avoid overlap / entangling of the nodes using force layout in D3.js. The nodes must be a bit far from each other ?
These are code changes , the links some times cut each other and some times nodes are too close to each other

```
force = d3.layout.force()
        .gravity(.2)
        .distance(100)
        .charge(-700)
        .size([700,700]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's dependent on your network, there are no fixed rules for making a network visualization display properly. One thing to experiment with is setting linkDistance or charge to be based on the weight value of a node, which indicates the degree centrality of a node (the number of connections it has). Something like:

```
d3.layout.force()
 .charge(function (d) {return d.weight * -500})
```